# SSH Remote Port Forwarding (Tunneling) not working publicly even with GatewayPorts yes

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, sshd

I have trouble enabling SSH remote port forwarding publicly.

On the client side:

`ssh -vvv -nNT -p 2222 -R \*:8882:localhost:22 xx@<server_address>`

Output:

> ...
>
> debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
>
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
>
> Authenticated to xxx.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:2222).
>
> debug1: Remote connections from *:8882 forwarded to local address localhost:22
>
> debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
>
> debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
>
> debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
>
> debug1: Entering interactive session.
>
> debug1: remote forward success for: listen *:8882, connect localhost:22
>
> debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed

On the server side: (which got GatewayPorts enabled, confirmed with `sshd -T`)

`netstat -an | grep 8882`

Output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8882            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8882                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

When connecting to localhost (`ssh -p 8882 xx@localhost`), it does work and i can login into the SSH shell of the client. However, `ssh` just hangs there and do nothing if I change `localhost` to my local ip, or even `127.0.0.1`, there is also no debug output at the client side, too.

As seen from the `netstat` output, it seems the port `8882` is bound to all interfaces and should work publicly, but it doesn't. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did You ever solve Your problem? I'm in the same predicament (apparently). In my case I have a self-compiled kernel/rootfs (5.7/Buildroot), so I might have goofed somewhere :/

Comment: @ZioByte I am sorry but no, I never did solve the issue. IIRC, I switched to another machine and it works again. Maybe it's due to hidden bugs in specific SSH versions, or maybe kernel versions? Not really sure...

Answer (score 3):

Setting in sshd_config to allow tunneling is `AllowTcpForwarding`. Remember to restart sshd to make it work.

Comment: `AllowTcpForwarding` is set to yes. It is confirmed by `ssh -T | grep allowtcpforwarding` and I still cannot connect the to port with my ip address other than `localhost`.

Comment: Do you have iptables enabled on the remote server?

Comment: No, i don't. The HTTP and SSH server are fine and accessible in the public, it's just the tunnel port not work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and after a morning's Google I found it is related to the iptables/firewall of the remote server. It seems the reason is the port 2222 is not open. Then I solve this problem by executing the following commands on the remote sever (CentOS 7)

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2222/tcp 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

It should work if directly editing iptables, but I do not try it. Although this answer is very late for this question, I wish it may help someone who faces the same problem.